# returning data from table using category_id from a category table from mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi everyone this is my first question here and i'll be very grateful if you could help me.

I have a table like this in mysql

```
//table items
id | item_name | description | link | category_id | is_active
```

And i have another table like this

```
//table categories
id  category_name | cat_description | is_active
```

I want to get all the data in `category_name` and get all the content from `item_name` if `is_active` column is on, and also if category `is_active` column is on.

I was trying to make a function that would retrieve all that data with html content and just if certain conditions are true.

My function is something like this:

```
    function getCatAndItems(){
    include "conn.php";
    $petition = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM items,categories WHERE is_active=1");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($petition)) {
        $filename = $row['nombre'];
        $url       = $row['url_document'];

    echo "<a href=../docs/files/$url'><li>&nbsp;".$filename."</li></a>";
  }
}
```

My goal is to bring the categories and if the categories are active and if the items table in the category_id is the same as the category id and `is_active` it will bring me also the data in the items table that share the same number.

I hope you understand me and hope you could help me, thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get using `JOIN`

```
SELECT items.name, items.description, items.link, categories.category_name, categories.cat_description
FROM categories
JOIN items 
ON categories.id = items.category_id
WHERE categories.is_active = 1
AND items.is_active = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `inner join` between these two tables would do the job done.

```
SELECT
      items.name,
      items.description,
      items.link,
      categories.category_name,
      categories.cat_description
FROM categories
INNER JOIN items ON categories.id = items.category_id
WHERE categories.is_active = 1
AND items.is_active = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your query :

```
select i.id,i.item_name,i.description,i.link,i.category_id,i.is_active,c.category_name 
               from items as i left join categories as c on i.category_id=c.id where 
               i.is_active=1 and c.is_active=1;
```